# Define a palindrome operator that duplicates the values on the stack in reverse order in postscript

Tags: post, postscript

Define a palindrome operator that duplicates the values on the stack in reverse order.

this is what i have so far and it not doing what i want it to do

`/palindrome {`
`1 dict begin`
 `count 1 gt`
`{`
`/first exch def`
`/second exch def`
`temp1 = first`
`temp2 = last`
`first = last`
`last = temp1`
   `}`
`} def`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of what you have written there doesn't make any sense in PostScript:

```
/palindrome
{
  1 dict begin
  count 1 gt 
  {
    /first exch def
    /second exch def
%% The following four lines are not valid PostScript
    temp1 = first
    temp2 = last
    first = last
    last = temp1
%% There is no '=' assignment operator in PostScript, in PS the = operator
%% pops one object from the stack and writes a text representation to stdout.
%% You have not defined any of the keys temp1, temp2 or last
%% in any dictionary. If executed I would expect this program to throw an
%% 'undefined' error in 'temp1'
  }
%% Given the 'count 1 gt' at the opening brace, I would expect this executable
%% array to be followed by a conditional, such as 'if'. Since it isn't this just
%% leaves the executable array '{....}' on the stack
} def
```

So overall I would expect this PostScript function to push a boolean on to the operand stack, true or false depending on whether the stack has at least 2 objects on it at the time of execution, and then an executable array on to the operand stack and exit.

If I were doing this I would store the stack into an array, then unload the array back to the stack and then iterate through the array from end to beginning. Something like:

```
%!

/palindrome
{
  count array astore
  aload
  dup length 1 sub -1 0 {
   1 index exch get
    exch
  } for
  pop
} def

(line 1)
2
3

(before palindrome\n) print
pstack
palindrome
(after palindrome\n) print
pstack
```

It's also possible (I have a working example here) to do this in a single pass without defining any extra storage objects (dictionaries or arrays) by using a for loop and manipulating the stack. That seems like a more elegant solution to me, and is left as an exercise for the reader :-)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but it might be useful to someone.

Using the built in **copy** and a reverse function,

```
%!

% n reverse - reverses top n stack elements
/reverse {
  -1 2 { 1 roll } for
} bind def

% makes a palindrome from the stack
/palin {
  count copy           % add a copy of the stack to the stack
  count 2 idiv reverse % reverse the top half of the stack
} bind def

[7 8] 5 (hello)        % put some items on the stack

pstack  % before - [7 8] 5 (hello)
palin
pstack  % after  - [7 8] 5 (hello) (hello) 5 [7 8]
```

alternatively, instead of calling **count** twice we can store it and reuse it,

```
/palin {
  1 dict begin
    count /stackcount exch def
    stackcount copy
    stackcount reverse 
  end
} bind def
```